# HTML/CSS - creating an "arrow" on one side of a DIV

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am transforming a div to give it a point on one end like an arrow. I've accomplished this using a second div and a CSS transform to rotate its borders 45 degrees. My issue is the background on the original div bleeds through and still forms a square. How can I solve this issue? I've created a fiddle at the below link, I would like the blue background of "Step 1" to end in the point instead of the flat edge. Thank you. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72vxy7ht/)

```
<ul class="progress">
    <li class="completed">
        <span>
            <span class="order">1 </span>Step 1
        </span>
        <div class="diagonal"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            <span class="order">2 </span>Step 2
        </span>
        <div class="diagonal"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            <span class="order">3 </span>Step 3
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 0;
}

.progress > li {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #bbb;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.progress > li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

.progress > li.completed {
    background-color: #0071bc;
}

.progress > li span {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
 }

.progress > li span .order {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #555;
    border-radius: 27px;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    line-height: 25px;
}


.diagonal {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: -7px;
}

.diagonal:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the [css triangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) could help you? You can use it in a :after pseudo element as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a right arrow/triangle like that by setting a transparent top and bottom border, then give a left border of the color you want the arrow to be. Then style it so it works with your layout.

```css
.progress {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 0;
}

.progress > li {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    position: relative;
}

.progress > li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

.progress > li.completed {
    background-color: #0071bc;
}

.progress > li:not(.completed) {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.progress > li span {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
 }

.progress > li span .order {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #555;
    border-radius: 27px;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.diagonal {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #bbb;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  z-index: 1;
}
.completed .diagonal {
  border-left-color: #0071bc;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progress">
    <li class="completed">
        <span>
            <span class="order">1 </span>Step 3
        </span>
        <div class="diagonal"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            <span class="order">2 </span>Step 2
        </span>
        <div class="diagonal"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
            <span class="order">3 </span>Step 3
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to replicate the border around the triangle like I have in my example?